# clusterdata Matlab function

Tags: matlab, statistics, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am using Matlab clusterdata function to classify my data (noise and non-noise) into 2 categories: noise and non-noise groups. The function works well except that sometimes it names all noise data as group 1 and all non-noise data as group 2. Sometimes it names all noise data as group 2 and all non-noise data as group 1.

How can I control it? I mean label all noise data as group 1.

Answer (score 0):

Having control over the name of the labels an unsupervised learning algorithm uses can generally be a problem. I suggets to try to evaluate some of the features of the data after doing the clustering to see if the labels are as you want them.

If all your data is in X (N x d) matrix, with a label vector Y(N x 1) taking values -1 and 1, you could evaluate the variance of each of the clusters. I suspect the noise data would exhibit higher variance, which could be used to see if the labels should be switched.

In the code below, 1 should be the non-noise, and -1 should be noise (this choice of labels (groups) makes it easier to flip the labels around).

```
%#Variance summed over all dimensions    
varL1 = sum(var(X(Y==1,:)));  
varL2=  sum(var(X(Y==-1,:)));

%#Flip labels if if L1 is higher than L2
if varL1 > varL2
    Y = Y * (-1);
end
```

If this works, you could afterwards change noise cluster to be group 1 and non-noise to group 2 by

```
Y(Y==1) = 2;  %#NB: The order of which these statements are evaluated is important.
Y(Y==-1) = 1;
```

Comment: You can switch labels 1 and 2 with simple `Y = 3 - Y`